# RxJava convert Single<String> object to String class

Tags: java, rx-java, micronaut

Is there a posibility to convert a Single object to String class?

Single < User > stringSingle = Single.just(User.getName());

String s = "";

**s**=**stringSingle;**

How can I assign **stringSingle** to the **s** variable?

Comment: Have you looked at a [Micronaut](https://piotrminkowski.com/2019/11/12/micronaut-tutorial-reactive/) tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have something like this.

```
import rx.Single;
import lombok.Getter;

public class TestClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Single<User> stringSingle = Single.just(new User("Peter", 9));
   final String[] s = new String[1];

   //Asynchronous and advisable 
   stringSingle.subscribe( result -> {
      s[0] = result.toString();
    });
    System.out.println(s[0]);
     
     //Blocking and not very advisible way of getting the value
    String s2 =   stringSingle.toBlocking().value().toString();
    System.out.println(s2);
  }
}

//Example of a possible User class to use.
class User{
  @Getter
  private String name;
  @Getter
  private int age ;

  public User( String nm,  int ag){
    name = nm;
    age = ag;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return "name " + getName() + " and age " + getAge();
  }
}
```

Results is

```
name Peter and age 9
name Peter and age 9
```

Comment: Thank you, but i'm using Reactive Java, with @ExecuteOn in the controller and I thought it s not a good idea to use `toBlocking()` . I want to get from response which is Single<HttpResponse<Entity>> object, the object attribute from the response(body). Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: You can subscribe to the Single observable and get the result asynchronously (when the value is ready). There is already an example in the solution I provided. 

`//Asynchronous and advisable 
   stringSingle.subscribe( result -> {
      s[0] = result.toString();
    });`

There are some other examples [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html)